# Remove Unused categorical values boxplot - R

Tags: r, dataframe, boxplot

I have the following code:

```
x = rnorm(30, 1, 1)
c = c(rep("x1",10), rep("x2",10), rep("x3",10))
df = dataframe(x,c)
boxplot(x ~ c, data=df)
```

It works great.  But if I decide I am no longer interested in seeing x3, remove it, and replot:

```
dfMod = subset(df, c %in% c("x1", "x2"))
boxplot(x ~ c,data=dfMod)
```

The boxplot still shows a column for x3.

[image]

Ive tried giving boxplot a hint using

```
boxplot(x~c,data=dfMod, names = c("x1", "x2"))
```

but this throws the error that names size is not right.  Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `droplevels` after `subset`

```
dfMod <- subset(df, c %in% c("x1", "x2"))    
dfMod$c <- droplevels(dfMod$c)
boxplot(x ~ c,data=dfMod)
```

You can also use `class` to change `factor` to `character` and subsetting inside `boxplot` call

```
class(df) <- c("numeric", "character")
boxplot(x ~ c, subset=c %in% c("x1", "x2"),  data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: So obviously this is an easy thing to do and I feel a little embarrassed for having to ask it on SO.  So I can get better handle on R terminology, what should I have googled to find the droplevels command?  "Remove unused categorical value from data frame column" didn't prove particularly helpful

Comment: If you write "get rid of unused factors in r" on google will give you  lots of results about dropping unused levels ;)