# boxplot on subset within a group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with vaccine uptake and various levels of geography in separate columns.  I want to show boxplots of vaccine uptake for GP practices by CCG within one health area.

The code I used in R:

```
boxplot(Percentuptake~CCGName, data=pertussis, subset=DCOCode %in% c("Q74 Eng Team"), 
      main="Maternal Pertussis Uptake", xlab="CCG Name",
      ylab="Maternal Pertussis Uptake (%)")
```

I get the plot I wanted but the x axis (and boxplot) has the CCG labels for all the health areas not just the one selected.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: Has already been answered a few times. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965333/remove-unused-categorical-values-boxplot-r